# Change the selection font color of a firemonkey grid via styles

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.4-sydney

I want to change the row select font color of a firemonkey TGrid via styles. I don't know how to do this.

Via code I can do this but I want to do it via styles. I know how to style the background of the grid or the background of the selected row because there are style entries for that. There is no style entry for 'text color selected'.

Using 10.5 Alexandria.

Comment: For `Fmx` matters it is always good to indicate which Delphi version you have as there has been several development phases. What have you tried, and why did it not work for you? Is there an entry for the font color in selected state in the style book? Which style do you prefer?

Comment: Well, if there are no style entry for 'selected text color', then you can't do it via styles.